# Java abstract method signature

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, polymorphism, abstract

I am quite confused about abstract method signitures that Java classes implement.

For example, consider:

```
interface Programmer {
    Object program();
}

class Linus implements Programmer {
    public String program() {
        return "goto end;";
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Linus().program());
    }
}
```

This is apparently acceptable, since anything expecting an Object to come from Linus.program() will get one (specifically, a String).

But now consider this:

```
interface OS {
    void run(String code);
}

class Linux implements OS {
    public void run(Object code) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Linux().run("print 'Hello world'");
    }
}
```

This fails to compile, and yields the error:

```
The type Linux must implement the inherited abstract method OS.run(String)
```

Now, anything could expected to be able to pass a String into any instance of the OS interface, and you could certainly do that with Linux.

I see no reason why the second one fails to compile. Of the consequences of having Java compile the second program, am I missing something that makes this prohibitive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing for the second case is method over-loading.
Signature of a method is "method-name" and "number and types of arguments"
In the second case you are changing the type of argument which compiler things is another method, and ask you to implement the abstracted (unimplemented) methods. And if you implement the methods present in the interface `public void run(String code)` then this method `public void run(Object code)` will be treated as an overloaded method.

**NOTE:** Method over-riding is never based on the return type of the method. As return type is not considered as method's signature

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass an instance of base class Object in place of an instance of class String but the reverse is valid. In your interface OS, the parameter to the run method is of type String and in the implementation class you are generalising the parameter to be of type Object which is not allowed. Hence, the compiler complains.

Comment: This doesn't explain it. I am calling on the Linux base class. If I were calling the OS interface, then this point would be valid. The Linux base class accepts all Objects, including Strings.

Comment: The bottom line is that you can not change the parameters in the contract enforced by the interface. Here, you are changing the type of the parameter from String to Object, which technically makes it a new method definition and not an implementation of the interface contract and hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

You say "Now, anything could expected to be able to pass a String into any instance of the OS interface, and you could certainly do that with Linux." => Problem is that you could, but are not required to.

Consider this: as Linux version of the method takes an Object as a parameter, you could try and pass a Collection, for example. Thus you would not respect the interface, which explicitely restricts the parameter to being a String. That is why Linux version of the method is not considered to be the "child" of OS version.

And as each method in the interface needs to have its "child", the compiler complains you did not implement a "child" for OS.run(String)

Comment: So what is the code that would be ambiguous or couldn't work?